# Texas Holdem: How to Score this Hand - Single Pair, 3 kickers

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, scoring

I have a question for you. It's a question that came up last night in a poker game and is still being debated by the group. Some say split, some say one winner. Please let me know how you would score this hand (see pic below). Please tell me who won, or if there was a tie, and also what the series of cards would be for the winning hand or tie. Also, if you're aware of any game variations that are played that would make both sides of the debate right (unlikely).

I'm not going to tell you what I think, because I don't want to bias your ruling. Just trying to get to the truth here.

Thanks so much!

[image: Debated Poker Hand]

Answer (score 11):

It's a split. If you take the highest scoring set of five cards, each player is holding a double king, queen, ten and nine. The eight of clubs and four of hearts are never considered in scoring.

[Here's](http://www.idiotsguides.com/hobbies-and-crafts/card-games/how-to-play-texas-holdem/) an explanation of this five-card scoring rule. Especially:

> Five might be the most important number in poker, if only because five cards make a complete poker hand. This is true no matter how many cards you’re dealt, whether seven, as in seven-card-stud, or just two, as in Hold’em.

Comment: Is there also an explicit rule that excludes suit colors as tiebreakers?

Comment: No suit in poker is better than any other in any respect, so they never break ties.

Comment: @KefSchecter No suit in *Texas Hold'em* is better than any other suit. There are common variants where suit may matter, for example determining who will Bring In in 7 card stud.

Comment: Let me clarify: no suit is better than any other when it comes to evaluating standard five-card poker hands.